# When should I use appcompat libraries android?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm writing a new app, and in this project I'm using the `minSdkVersion = 21`  (lollipop), so my question is: **should I use any appcompat library once I'm targeting a quite new API**?

Comment: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/06/android-support-library/

Comment: 1/2 This question is bound to bring opinionated answers. First of all, you should definitely use support-v4, it has latest updates in Fragment implementation. Use support-vector-drawable, it has latest updates in VectorDrawable implementation. Secondly, if you *don't* use appcompat-v7 and want to use design support library, use [cwac-crossport](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport).

Comment: 2/2 Thirdly, appcompat-v7 backports support for theme attributes in XML colors from API 23. Finally, there have been theme attributes introduced after API 21 and appcompat-v7 backports them. There have been functionalities backported, such as auto-size text from API 26. Depends on you if you want to pay the price of bigger APK for feature backports and simpler use.

Answer (score 5):

**You should & you need to.**

**why:**

1. android os is emerging new features and updates day by day. To give these features & updates in older version this is the way.
2. Consistent UI looks for all versions.

check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Be2mJzP-Uw) out.

Answer (score 1):

In Android `appcompat-v7`, as with `Theme.Material`, supports the notion of a custom theme defining colors, like **colorPrimary** and **colorAccent**. Native `Theme.Material` widgets on Android 5.0+, and supported widgets in `appcompat-v7`, will use those colors in accordance with the Material Design guidelines.

> The support library injects the compatibility code automatically. The
>   classes provided by the support library are only needed when writing a
>   new custom view. In this case you have to extend the `AppCompat` views
>   in order to get the new properties such as **tint**.